# color styling tablecell based upon value

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to style tablecells based upon the text value of the cell. This is being done on specific fields to draw user attention These tablecells are hosted inside of a formview with an itemTemplate of asp:table object. The cells have an ID and are set to run at the server side so that I can grab them from codebehind.

I attempted to hook into the individual cells by handling the onDatabound, onPrerender, onLoad events of the tablecell. onPreRender is used in my code snippet but results were same on all three tablecell events. In handling these events I always had a string.empty for the text property instead of the actual value (even after databind was called). Because I didn't have the actual value my comparisons did not pass and my color styling did not get set as desired.

edit: I also tried handling the databound event of my formview to get to my cell values. No luck there either.

Here's relevant markup:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvShipments" runat="server" DefaultMode="readonly">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Table ID="tblShipments" runat="server" GridLines="Both">
                        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                            <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="tbcCartonSizeOverride" CssClass="table-displayrow centerText" OnPreRender="tbcCartonSizeOverride_PreRender"><%#Eval("CartonSizeOverRide")%></asp:TableCell>
```

Here's relevant codebehind

```
Protected Sub tbcCartonSizeOverride_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    markAflag(CType(sender, TableCell))
End Sub
Private Sub markAflag(ByRef cell As TableCell)
    If cell.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Orange
    Else
        cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not understanding why this isn't working. Unless my Eval markup solves AFTER prerender event?

Thanks for reading. I don't work with asp often so it's possible I have something simple confused here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this issue by setting some datakeys on my formview object and doing a findcontrol call at runtime to get a reference to my table on the page. Here's some sample code that demonstrates what I did.

```
 Private Sub colorReturncode()
    Dim schedreturncode As Integer
    schedreturncode = FormView1.DataKey(1)
    Dim qtable As New Table

    qtable = CType(FormView1.FindControl("table1"), Table)
    If schedreturncode = 0 Then
        qtable.Rows(4).Cells(2).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        qtable.Rows(4).Cells(2).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    ElseIf schedreturncode = -1 Then
        qtable.Rows(4).Cells(2).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

    Else
        qtable.Rows(4).Cells(2).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        qtable.Rows(4).Cells(2).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    End If
End Sub
```